# codeigniter : Use 2 databases and hosted website

Tags: codeigniter-3

I'm facing a very tough difficulty since a day ago, i still can't find any solutions regardless all my researches. My hosted website on bluehost has 2 databases, the first one is a mysql database which i connect to database easily and a sql database which i can't connect to it. I learn that i should have extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_nts.dll, extension=php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll in php.ini according my php version.

If my website is hosted how can i connect to the second sql database ?

My database file is like this :

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

 $db['default'] = array(
'dsn'   => '',
'hostname' => 'localhost',
'username' => 'ausername',
'password' => 'apassword',
'database' => 'adatabase',
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
 );


  $db['second_database'] = array(
'dsn'       => '',
 'hostname' => 'aaa.bbb-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
 'port' => '14733',
'username' => 'aa',
'password' => 'apassword1',
'database' => 'adatabase1',
'dbdriver' => 'sqlsrv',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt'  => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

When i load the page  i have this error :

**Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in /home2/admedica/public_html/admedicall_v1/system/database/drivers/sqlsrv/sqlsrv_driver.php on line 144**

Comment: Good to see you didn't post any sensitive information like your usernames and passwords :)

Comment: thank you so much, i did not do that, i changed them before posting.

Comment: Please don't forget me.

Comment: Try using the `pdo` driver, this driver also supports MSSQL

Comment: If i use it i don't have to put any dll file in the php folder of bluehost server ?

Comment: I try to use 'dbdriver' => 'pdo', and 'dsn'  => 'mysql:host....  instead of hostname i have this error :  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out

Filename: controllers/Admin.php

Line Number: 6